# accessing a PHP object (in another file) within a jquery code. Help

Tags: php, jquery, variables

I have a json object in a PHP file and I want to access it from a JQuery.js file, which both located in an index.php page.

Do you have an idea how to do that ?

**index.php**

```
<?php 
include('theFileThatContainsJson.php'); // say it's $json
?>
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
.............
</body>
</html>
```

and here, what we have in **jquery.js** file, you can see my work (which doesn't work ;) ):

```
    $.getJSON(<?php echo '$json'; ?>, function(data){ .... }
```

How to solve the puzzle <<< at least for me at this moment :) ?

Answer (score 2):

One way (nasty!) would be to do something like this..

```
<script language="javascript" src="jquery.js.php?data=<?php echo base64_encode($json) ?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

.. and on your `jquery.js.php` file:

```
$.getJSON(<?php echo base64_decode($_GET['data']) ?>, function(data) { ... });
```

Of course, this is terrible practice and shouldn't really be done.. The best ways could include:

- Have `theFileThatContainsJson.php` to simply `echo` the JSON, and have `jquery.js` just do an AJAX request to get the data
- Have `theFileThatContainsJson.php` actually print out a `<script></script>` tag that contains a Javascript variable which you can use

Answer (score 0):

if json not big:

```
$.getJSON('<?php echo '$json'; ?>', function(data){ .... }
```

or even

```
$.getJSON('<?php include('theFileThatContainsJson.php'); ?>', function(data){ .... }
```

in second case theFileThatContainsJson.php should echo that json.
in both cases  should be in body of page

anyway I would not suggest to make it like that (use ajax for example)